# How to use pipes correctly with child processes?

Tags: c, pipe, unistd.h

```
//I want to execute pwd|sort > file.txt

char commands[2][30] = {"pwd", "sort"};
char directory [2][30] = {"/usr/bin/pwd", "/usr/bin/sort"}
char outputFile[30] = "file.txt"
int totalCommands = 2;
bool isOutputFilePresent = true;

//creating two pipes
int fd1[2];
int fd2[2];
pipe(fd1);
pipe(fd2);
//Closing the writing ends but keeping the reading ends open as closing them will destroy both the pipes
close (fd1[1]);
close (fd2[1]);

//loop to execute each command by creating a child process in each iteration
for (int i = 0; i < totalCommands; ++i)
{
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        if (i == totalCommands - 1)
        {
            if (i%2 == 0)
            {
                close(fd1[1]);
                close(fd2[0]);
                dup2(fd1[0], 0);
                dup2(fd2[1], 1);
            }
            else
            {
                close(fd2[1]);
                close(fd1[0]);
                dup2(fd2[0], 0);
                dup2(fd1[1], 1);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (i%2 == 0)
            { 
                close(fd2[0]);
                close(fd2[1]);
                close(fd1[1]);
                dup2(fd1[0], 0);
            }
            else
            {
                close(fd1[0]);
                close(fd1[1]);
                close(fd2[1]);
                dup2(fd2[0], 0);
            }
            if(isOutputFilePresent)
            {
                int outputFD = open (outputFile, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT);
                dup2(outputFD, 1);
            }

        }
        execv(directory[i], commands[i]) //ignore the fact that i am passing command name instead of argument vector
    }
    wait(NULL);
}
```

As the child process will inherit its own FDs of the pipe, I closed unused pipes in each process and by using dup2, assigned stdout and stdin FDs to it. But this code has a logical error and I guess its because of not using the pipes correctly. So where am I mistaken in the concept of pipes and what could be the solution to this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You close the write end of the pipes immediately after opening them. Therefore nothing can write to those pipes:

```
pipe(fd1);
pipe(fd2);
//Closing the writing ends but keeping the reading ends open as closing them will destroy both the pipes
close (fd1[1]);
close (fd2[1]);
```

Do this:

1. Create two pipes: A and B
2. Fork/spawn new child process
3. Parent closes write-end of A and read-end of B
4. Child closes read-end of A and write-end of B

Thus the child writes to A, and the parent reads from A.
The parent writes to B, and the child reads from B.

The [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) for pipe(2) give you example code that shows you how to do this:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int pipefd[2];
   pid_t cpid;
   char buf;

   if (argc != 2) {
       fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <string>\n", argv[0]);
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   if (pipe(pipefd) == -1) {
       perror("pipe");
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   cpid = fork();
   if (cpid == -1) {
       perror("fork");
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   if (cpid == 0) {    /* Child reads from pipe */
       close(pipefd[1]);          /* Close unused write end */

       while (read(pipefd[0], &buf, 1) > 0)
           write(STDOUT_FILENO, &buf, 1);

       write(STDOUT_FILENO, "\n", 1);
       close(pipefd[0]);
       _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

   } else {            /* Parent writes argv[1] to pipe */
       close(pipefd[0]);          /* Close unused read end */
       write(pipefd[1], argv[1], strlen(argv[1]));
       close(pipefd[1]);          /* Reader will see EOF */
       wait(NULL);                /* Wait for child */
       exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
   }
}
```

Comment: If we close one end of a pipe and call a fork, will child process also inherit that it as closed?

Comment: Try it yourself and see :)  (I believe the answer is that a child inherits *open* file handles. A closed one won't be re-opened.)